# Regex thinks I'm nesting, but I'm not

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote this regexp to capture the strings below.

```
\!\[(.*?)?\]
```

All the strings below should match and return an optional string that's inside the first set of square brackets.

```
![]
![caption]
![]()
![caption]()
![caption][]
```

The problem is that this string also matches and returns `][` because the regex thinks it's between the first `[`  and last `]`.

```
![][] // Should not match, but does and returns "]["
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure about that regex matching `][`? Plus the last `?` is redundant. `*?` already takes into consideration 'no match'.

Comment: I'm using scriptular.com and it shows me that in the results. Could scripular be broken? Here's a share link http://scriptular.com/#%5C!%5C%5B(.*%3F)%3F%5C%5D%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22!%5B%5D%22%2C%22!%5Bcaption%5D%22%2C%22!%5B%5D()%22%2C%22!%5Bcaption%5D()%22%2C%22!%5B%5D%5B%5D%22%2C%22!%5Bcaption%5D%5B%5D%22%2C%22%22%5D

Comment: Sorry about the long link, but that's what it generates.

Comment: Seems to me like it should *match*, it just shouldn't capture `][`. Debuggex seems to show it working the way you expect.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton The syntax for a link is `[text](http://stackoverflow.com/)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `?` outside `(.*?)`, that is redundant.

```
var myArray = ["![abc]","![caption]", "![def]()", "![caption]()","![caption][]"];
myArray.forEach(function(current) {
    console.log(/!\[(.*?)\]/.exec(current)[1]);
});
```

**Output**

```
abc
caption
def
caption
caption
```

Check how the RegEx works [here](http://regex101.com/r/rQ0pJ0)

Comment: Thank you. I thought the `?` was needed because the caption was option. I'm not sure if I should ask another question, but I want the regex to not match if thee second set of have something in them. So `![](something in here will stop the match)` or `![][something in here will also stop the match]`.

Comment: +1. Also, I just noticed that `\!\[(.*?)?\]` works as intended on PCRE but not on JS' engine. Hmmm.

Comment: @thefourtheye No, I mean, in PCRE, `\!\[(.*?)?\]` matches `![]` (intended) but in JS, it matches `![][]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
\!\[([^\]]*)\]
```

It means that it expects a "last" ] but makes internal ones invalid.
This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is this if you want to ignore catching the things like this `![[]]`

```
\!\[([^\[\]]*)\]
```