# Greediness behaving differently in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20920296/1578604) which made me realise that greediness of quantifiers is not always the same in certain regex engines. Taking the regex from that question and modifying it a bit:

```
!\[(.*?)*\]
```

<sup>(I know that `*` is redundant here, but I found what's following to be quite an interesting behaviour).</sup>

And if we try to match against:

```
![][][]
```

I expected to get the first capture group to be empty, because `(.*?)` is lazy and will stop at the first `]` it comes across. This is indeed what happens in:

- [PCRE](http://regex101.com/r/lZ2dI3)
- [Python](http://regex101.com/r/nX3qQ3)
- but *not* [Javascript](http://regex101.com/r/wV6nF1) where it matches the whole `][][`. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unknown008/Lgr56/))

I looked around with some other languages, for instance [ruby](http://rubular.com/r/d4y2P8RunU), [java](http://ideone.com/HKVtUn), [C#](http://ideone.com/8ULqZh) but all behave like I expected them to (i.e. return empty capture groups).

(regexplanet's [golang](http://fiddle.re/qdtt2) flavour apparently also gets non-empty capture groups)

It seems that JavaScript's regex engine is interpreting the second `*` to convert `.*?` from lazy to greedy. Note that converting the second `*` to `*?` seems to make the regex work as I expected (as does removing the quantifier completely, because I know that it's being redundant in this situation, but that's not the point).

`*` was used in the regex, but this behaviour is similar with `+`, `?` or `{m,n}` and converting them to their lazy version gives the same results as with `*?`.

Does anyone know what's really happening?

Comment: What would you expect in this case: `(a+?)*` match agains "aaaaa" (starting with an non-empty match for the lazy part)

Comment: @basilikum That's a little different, but okay. The first `a` will match first, because that's the least requirement. Then stop there, move outside to find a greedy `*`. So `(a+?)` is repeated, matching a second `a`. And so on and so forth until all `a` are matched.

Comment: The output from regex101 suggests not that the outer asterisk makes the inner regex greedy (because in that case, group 1 would have captured `][][`). The fact that it captures `[` would be expected with a regex like `!\[(.?)*\]`, so perhaps the inner asterisk has been "optimized" away...looks like a bug in any case...

Comment: @TimPietzcker I didn't really pay attention to that. I guess it could be a bug (it's not only on regex101 though, but then, you might also have meant that to be a bug in JavaScript in general), but using `.?` means you're also using a greedy quantifier. Another fun fact, `!\[(.?)*\]` gives `[` in JS, but an empty string in PCRE and Python!

Comment: @Jerry: You're right; Python is correct here (that empty string is the empty string before the last `]`)...I've tried your regex on Chrome, IE and Firefox, they all show the same result. I've posted the question on RegexBuddy's internal forum - perhaps our regex gure Jan Goyvaerts can shed some light on this.

Comment: I think it is related to how the engines handle empty string repetition... (an empty string is matched for the pattern inside a repetition). From my testing and some deduction, PCRE looks like it will stop a repetition if it detects empty string being matched twice in a row (note how `((.*?)*)` [produces empty string](http://regex101.com/r/bJ2vY1) for the inner capturing group even when something is matched for the whole pattern).

Comment: As for JS, I can't fathom the rule behind. See this 2 cases for yourself: [1 with `((.*?){1,4})`](http://regex101.com/r/jJ3mP2) and [2 with `((.*?){0,4})`](http://regex101.com/r/tW7uG0)

Comment: @nhahtdh I think those might be related. For PCRE, I understand it like that when there's an outer match but no inner match: `(.*?)` matches the character, then matches 'nil' after the character which is what's stored in the capture group (note, this only happens with `g` flag), which also seem to say that laziness is not completely lazy, but they try to match empty instead of ending the match. JS is a mess xP Seems like in `{0,4}`, it tries to take 4 chars, then accepts the 0, while in `{1,4}`, takes 4 chars, backtracks one char to allow a last single char, before `.*?` takes the 'nil'.

Comment: If you open the links I have shared so far, they have different result on IE. One strange thing is that the example in the question is **the same** on even IE. I don't know whether this is considered as JS quirks, or a bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short answer

The behavior is defined in [ECMA-262 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in section **15.10.2 Pattern Semantics**, especially in **15.10.2.5** where it discusses the semantics of the production *Term :: Atom Quantifier*.

As a slight generalization: Let E be **a pattern that can match empty string**. If there exists an input string S where empty string is the first matchable choice in E, patterns which contain a **greedy** repetition of pattern E are affected. For example:

```
(a*?)*              against     aaaa
!\[(.*?)*\]         against     ![][][]
(.*?){1,4}          against     asdf
(|a)*               against     aaaa
(a|()|b){0,4}       against     aaabbb
```

Firefox and other Webkit-based browsers seems to follow the specs closely, while IE is off the specs in the case when there is no sequel to the affected pattern.

### Long answer

The relevant part of the specs is quoted below. Some part of the specs is omitted ([...]) to keep the discussion relevant. I will explain by condensing the information from the specs while keeping it simple.

#### Vocabulary

> - A *State* is an ordered pair (*endIndex*, *captures*) where *endIndex* is an integer and *captures* is an internal array of *NcapturingParens* values. *States* are used to represent partial match states in the regular expression matching algorithms. The *endIndex* is one plus the index of the last input character matched so far by the pattern, while *captures* holds the results of capturing parentheses. [...]. Due to backtracking, many *States* may be in use at any time during the matching process.
> - A *MatchResult* is either a *State* or the special token **failure** that indicates that the match failed.

There should be no confusion here. *State* keeps track of the position that has been processed so far (and also the captures, which we are not interested in for the moment). *MatchResult*, well, is the match result (duh!).

> - A *Continuation* procedure is an internal closure (i.e. an internal procedure with some arguments already bound to values) that takes one *State* argument and returns a *MatchResult* result. If an internal closure references variables bound in the function that creates the closure, the closure uses the values that these variables had at the time the closure was created. The *Continuation* attempts to match the remaining portion (specified by the closure's already-bound arguments) of the pattern against the input String, starting at the intermediate state given by its *State* argument. If the match succeeds, the *Continuation* returns the final *State* that it reached; if the match fails, the *Continuation* returns **failure**.
> - A *Matcher* procedure is an internal closure that takes two arguments -- a *State* and a *Continuation* -- and returns a *MatchResult* result. A *Matcher* attempts to match a middle subpattern (specified by the closure's already-bound arguments) of the pattern against the input String, starting at the intermediate state given by its *State* argument. The *Continuation* argument should be a closure that matches the rest of the pattern. After matching the subpattern of a pattern to obtain a new *State*, the *Matcher* then calls *Continuation* on that new *State* to test if the rest of the pattern can match as well. If it can, the *Matcher* returns the *State* returned by *Continuation*; if not, the *Matcher* may try different choices at its choice points, repeatedly calling *Continuation* until it either succeeds or all possibilities have been exhausted.

A *Matcher* contains code to match a subpattern that it represents, and it will call *Continuation* to continue the match. And *Continuation* contains code to continue the match from where *Matcher* left off. They both accepts *State* as an argument to know where to start matching.

#### Production *Term* :: *Atom Quantifier*

> The production *Term* :: *Atom Quantifier* evaluates as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *Atom* to obtain a Matcher *m*.
> 2. Evaluate *Quantifier* to obtain the three results: an integer *min*, an integer (or ∞) *max*, and Boolean *greedy*.
> 3. If *max* is finite and less than *min*, then throw a **SyntaxError** exception.
> 4. Let *parenIndex* be the number of left capturing parentheses in the entire regular expression that occur to the left of this production expansion's *Term*. [...]
> 5. Let *parenCount* be the number of left capturing parentheses in the expansion of this production's *Atom*. [...]
> 6. Return an internal Matcher closure that takes two arguments, a State *x* and a Continuation *c*, and performs the following:
>
>    1. Call RepeatMatcher(*m, min, max, greedy, x, c, parenIndex, parenCount*) and return its result.

Take note that `m` is the Matcher for the *Atom* that is being repeated, and Continuation *c* is passed in from the code generated from higher level production rules.

> The abstract operation *RepeatMatcher* takes eight parameters, a Matcher *m*, an integer *min*, an integer (or ∞) *max*, a Boolean *greedy*, a State *x*, a Continuation *c*, an integer *parenIndex*, and an integer *parenCount*, and performs the following:
>
> 1. If *max* is zero, then call *c(x)* and return its result.
> 2. Create an internal Continuation closure *d* that takes one State argument *y* and performs the following:
>
>    1. If *min* is zero and *y*'s *endIndex* is equal to *x*'s *endIndex*, then return **failure**.
>    2. If *min* is zero then let *min2* be zero; otherwise let *min2* be *min* - 1.
>    3. If *max* is ∞, then let *max2* be ∞; otherwise let *max2* be *max* - 1.
>    4. Call RepeatMatcher(*m, min2, max2, greedy, y, c, parenIndex, parenCount*) and return its result.
> 3. Let *cap* be a fresh copy of *x*'s *captures* internal array.
> 4. For every integer *k* that satisfies *parenIndex* < *k* and *k* ? *parenIndex* + *parenCount*, set *cap*[*k*] to **undefined**.
> 5. Let *e* be *x*'s *endIndex*.
> 6. Let *xr* be the State (*e, cap*).
> 7. If *min* is not zero, then call *m(xr, d)* and return its result.
> 8. If *greedy* is **false**, then
>
>    1. Call *c(x)* and let *z* be its result.
>    2. If *z* is not **failure**, return *z*.
>    3. Call *m(xr, d)* and return its result.
> 9. Call *m(xr, d)* and let *z* be its result.
> 10. If *z* is not **failure**, return *z*.
> 11. Call *c(x)* and return its result.

Step 2 defines a Continuation *d* where we try to match another instance of the repeated Atom, which is later called in step 7 (*min* > 0 case), step 8.3 (lazy case) and step 9 (greedy case) via the Matcher `m`.

Step 5 and 6 creates a copy of the current State, for backtracking purpose, and to detect empty string match in step 2.

The steps from here on describes 3 separate cases:

- Step 7 covers the case where the quantifier has non-zero *min* value. Greediness regardless, we need to match at least *min* instances of Atom, before we are allowed to call the Continuation *c*.
- Due to the condition in step 7, *min* is 0 from this point on. Step 8 deals with the case where the quantifier is lazy. Step 9, 10, 11 deals with the case where the quantifier is greedy. Note the reversed order of calling.

Calling *m(xr, d)* means matching one instance of the Atom, then calling Continuation *d* to continue the repetition.

Calling Continuation *c(x)* means getting out of the repetition and matching whatever comes next. Note how Continuation *c* is passed to the RepeatMatcher inside Continuation *d*, so that it is available to all subsequent iteration of the repetition.

#### Explanation of the quirk in JavaScript RegExp

**Step 2.1** is the culprit that causes the discrepancy in the result between PCRE and JavaScript.

> 1. If *min* is zero and *y*'s *endIndex* is equal to *x*'s *endIndex*, then return **failure**.

The condition *min* = 0 is reached when the quantifier originally has 0 as *min* (`*` or `{0,n}`) or via step 7, which must be called as long as *min* > 0 (original quantifier is `+` or `{n,}` or `{n,m}`).

When *min* = 0 **and** the quantifier is greedy, Matcher *m* will be called (in step 9), which attempts to match an instance of Atom and call Continuation *d* that is set up in step 2. Continuation *d* will recursively call RepeatMatcher, which in turn will call Matcher *m* (step 9) again.

Without step 2.1, if Matcher *m* has empty string as its first possible choice to advance ahead in the input, the iteration will (theoretically) continue forever without advance ahead. Given the limited features that JavaScript RegExp supports (no forward-declared back-reference or other fancy features), there is no need to go ahead with another iteration when the current iteration matches empty string - an empty string is going to be matched again anyway. Step 2.1 is JavaScript's method of dealing with repetition of empty string.

As set up in step 2.1, when *min* = 0, the **JavaScript** regex engine will prune when an empty string is matched by the Matcher *m* (return **failure**). This **effectively rejects "empty string repeated finitely many times is an empty string"**.

Another side effect of step 2.1 is that from the point when *min* = 0, as long as there is one instance where Matcher `m` matches non-empty string, the last repetition of *Atom* is guaranteed to be non-empty.

In contrast, it *seems* **PCRE** (and other engines) accepts "empty string repeated finitely many times is an empty string", and continue on with the rest of the pattern. This explains the behavior of PCRE in the cases listed above. As for the algorithm, PCRE stops the repetition after matching empty string twice in a row.

Comment: Wonderful answer, +1!

Comment: +1 I think I'll have to read that many more times to get it properly, thank you!

Comment: **Short, _short_ answer:** Just don't do that.  There's no excuse for using nested constructs like `(.*?)*` or `(.*)*`, that aren't required to consume even one character.  In fact, I would like to see regex compilers treat that as a syntax error, just as some of them do for quantified assertions like `\b+` or `(?<=X)?`.

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests and found that in Firefox and Chrome, if a group has a greedy quantifier and directly or indirectly contains one or more lazy quantifiers with zero as the minimum number of iterations, then for the iterations of the greedy quantifier where the minimum number of iterations has already been satisfied, the leftmost lazy quantifier that can match one or more iterations will match one iteration if the group would find a zero-length match if the lazy quantifier were to match zero iterations.

E.g. `(.{0,2}?){5,8}` matches "abc" in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" because `.{0,2}?` matches one iteration for iterations 6, 7, and 8 of `{5,8}`.

If there are tokens after the group with the greedy quantifier that can't be matched, then the lazy quantifier expands its number of iterations.  The permutation with zero iterations is never attempted.  But the greedy quantifier can still backtrack to its minimum number of iterations.

On the same subject string, `(.{0,3}?){5,6}[ad]` matches "abcd" while `(.{0,3}?){5,6}a` matches "a".

If there is anything else inside the group that finds a match, then the lazy quantifiers behave as they do in other regex engines.

The same happens in Internet Explorer if and only if there are tokens that are not optional after the group with the greedy quantifier.  If there are no tokens after the group or they are all optional then IE behaves like most other regex engines do.

The explanation for the behavior in Firefox and Chrome seems to be the combination of two steps in section 15.10.2.5 in the JavaScript standard.  Step 2.1 for RepeatMatcher makes the regex engine fail zero-length iterations of quantifiers that have already matched the minimum number of required iterations, instead of merely halting continued iteration.  Step 9 evaluates whatever comes after a lazy quantifier before evaluating the lazy quantifier itself.  In these examples that includes the continued repetition of the greedy quantifier.  When this greedy quantifier fails in step 2.1, the lazy quantifier is forced to repeat at least once.

So to answer whether this is a bug, I would say it is a bug in the JavaScript specification.  There is no benefit to this behavior and makes JavaScript regexes needlessly different from all other (popular) backtracking regex engines.  I do not expect that future JavaScript specifications will change this though.

Opera behaves differently.  `(.{0,2}?){5,8}` matches "abcd" while `(.{0,2}?){6,8}` matches "abcde".  Opera seems to force the lazy quantifier to match at least one iteration for all but the first iteration of the greedy quantifier, and then stop iterating when the greedy quantifier has found the required minimum number of iterations.

I recommend not using groups or alternatives in which everything is optional.  Make sure each alternative and each group matches something.  If the group needs to be optional, use `?` to make the whole group optional, instead of making everything inside the group optional.  This will reduce the number of permutations the regex engine has to try.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Just as a note, I would never use such a regex, I came across it from the question I linked in my own question =P. I think that you introduced another interesting point. I would have expected `(.{0,3}?){5,6}[ad]` to match only `a` (if anything, after seeing what happens), or `(.{0,2}?){5,8}` to match just the same as `(.{0,2}?){5,6}`, but instead, it matches like `(.{0,2}?){1,4}`. To me, it seems that `(.{0,3}?){5,6}` would match greedily (both inside and outside) until it matches (thus `d` instead of `a`). Another example `(.{0,3}?){1,10}[cd]` prefers `abcd` to `abc`.

Comment: Check rule 2.1 in section 15.10.2.5 of ECMA specs. This rule seems to cause the effect we see.

Answer (score 2):

This is not answering *why* grediness is behaving differently in Javascript but it shows that this is not a bug and it was tested to behave so.
I will take as example google's v8 engine. I found a similar example in their tests.

**/test/mjsunit/third_party/regexp-pcre.js:**

```
line 1085: res[1006] = /([a]*?)*/;
line 4822: assertToStringEquals("aaaa,a", res[1006].exec("aaaa "), 3176);
```

https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/test/mjsunit/third_party/regexp-pcre.js#1085

This code works well for Javascript http://regex101.com/r/nD0uG8 but it does not have the same output for PCRE php and python.

**UPDATE:**
About your question:

> It seems that JavaScript's regex engine is interpreting the second * to convert .*? from lazy to greedy

https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc#5157

```
RegExpQuantifier::QuantifierType quantifier_type = RegExpQuantifier::GREEDY;
if (current() == '?') {
    quantifier_type = RegExpQuantifier::NON_GREEDY;
    Advance();
} else if (FLAG_regexp_possessive_quantifier && current() == '+') {
    // FLAG_regexp_possessive_quantifier is a debug-only flag.
    quantifier_type = RegExpQuantifier::POSSESSIVE;
    Advance();
}
```

Comment: Nice. If that's not a bug, I do wonder why was meant to behave like so. Would be much simpler to have `/(a)*/` for instance.

Comment: @Jerry I updated my answer regarding conversion from lazy to greedy

Comment: Cool, it's awesome to get to see the inners of how it's functioning! It's massive as well though ^^; Okay, looking at this part, we see that having `?` makes it lazy. Thing now is, possessive quantifiers are a whole different world, and JS is, to date, unable to handle possessive quantifiers (greedy: `.*`, lazy: `.*?`, possessive: `.*+`). I guess it's yet another mystery! Or I'm missing a point somewhere...

Comment: Just try to understand [this simple pattern](http://regex101.com/r/uA7lL3) `a(.*?)*d` on the string `abbbcd`. Whereas Javascript `$1` contains `c`, PCRE contains a *zero-width match*. You tell the regex engine to [backtrack](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) as soon as you throw  a `*` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) after a [capture-group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: PCRE regex engine iterates the lazy part `.*?` to zero-width before it meets `d` whereas Javascript behaves differently and holds the last *non zero-width match* `c` in $1 when pushing towards `d`. PCRE is 1 step ahead, starting over the last iteration with a zero-width match. This is portable to your example. In my opionion it is a backtracking-difference and I understand PCRE better.

Comment: `It seems that if the last character was ? it was marked as NON_GREEDY but if the current is neither+ nor ? it becomes GREEDY` It doesn't really make any sense here, though. The code is just stating the obvious.

Comment: @nhahtdh I removed it. Hope you feel better, I was just trying to help.

Comment: @EmilCondrea: No, I mean quoting the code snippet doesn't explain the behavior we see. The engine doesn't do the conversion there. It just simply parse the regex, without modifying it.