# Conditional Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text:

```
<pre id="lyricsText">
__Verse 1
At the starting of the week
At summit talks, you'll hear them speak
It's only Monday

Negotiations breaking down
See those leaders start to frown
It's sword and gun day

__Chorus 1
Tomorrow never comes until it's too late

__Verse 2
You could be sitting taking lunch
The news will hit you like a punch
It's only Tuesday

You never thought we'd go to war
After all the things we saw
It's April Fools' day

__Chorus 1 (R:2)
Tomorrow never comes until it's too late

__Verse 3
You hear a whistling overhead
Are you alive or are you dead?
It's only Thursday

You feel a shaking on the ground
A billion candles burn around
Is it your birthday?

__Chorus 1 (R:2)
Tomorrow never comes until it's too late

__Outro
Make tomorrow come, I think it's too late
</pre>
```

and I'm trying to capture the headers. To do that I use this pattern:

```
var headers = /__.*/g;
```

which works fine, but I want to exclude `(R:2)` or anything similar to that. I'm using another pattern to capture and modify `(R:x)` parts:

```
/(\(R.{0,2}\))/g
```

I couldn't find a way to make them work together.

How do I write capture `/__.*/` and if exist exclude `/\(R.{0,2}\)/` ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjmf4/)

Comment: So for `__Chorus 1 (R:2)` you want to capture `__Chorus 1 `?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that for `__Chorus 1 (R:2)` you wish to match `__Chorus 1`, this would do it:

```
/__(.(?!\(R.{0,2}\)))*/g;
```

Matches as many characters as it can until the next sequence is `(R.{2})`

Output on your fiddle:

```
["__Verse 1", "__Chorus 1", "__Verse 2", "__Chorus 1", "__Verse 3", "__Chorus 1", "__Outro"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var headers = /__[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?=\(R:\d\))?/g;
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gjmf4/3/

Comment: Not sure why my answer got so much more attention. I started out pretty much exactly like this except without the final `?`, realised it *only* matched the titles with `(R..)` on the end so changed approach entirely - oblivious to the fact that `?` after the lookahead would have fixed it..

Comment: @OGHaza Well, what might have cause this is that you cannot put quantifiers on lookarounds.

Comment: @Jerry by quantifiers your referring to the `?`?  I am not a regex genius and this is actually what I was hoping to do, put something out there that works and get some feedback.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yup, `?` is indeed a quantifer, just like `+` or `*` or `{1,2}`. I just saw the question myself, but if you want to put `?` on a lookahead, you need to group it first, something like that: `(?:(?=\(R:\d\)))?`

Comment: @Jerry Then why does my fiddle work?  I'm noticing it the expression does not work in RegExr though.

Comment: This also solves the problem, but previously it didn't capture the numbering at the end of the headers. Also I'm using `\(R.{0,2}\)` on purpose because there are some `(R)`s without any digits next to it in some other texts so I suppose `\(R:\d\)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I was just thinking same. Maybe there's something more into it. Well, JS' regex sure has its weirdness at times, one of them being [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20921288/1578604). Might be worth digging into.

Comment: @Jerry Learned something new about quantifiers so thank you.  Found this mentioned: `Many regex flavors, including those used by Perl and Python, only allow fixed-length strings. You can use literal text, character escapes, Unicode escapes other than \X, and character classes. You cannot use quantifiers or backreferences.`

Comment: @KevinBowersox Ahh, that's yet another issue with another type of lookaround: lookbehinds. It doesn't have anything to do with what we have here, unfortunately ^^;